# is there any difference between 1.1em and 1.05em?

Tags: css

is there any difference on browser between `1.1em` and `1.05em`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well yes, they're different values. You probably won't notice any different unless the base size is sufficiently large though as most browsers will just round it. But they are certainly different.

Comment: but in both option font looks in same size.

Comment: Well yeah, like I said.. the browser will just round it to the nearest pixel if your base size is small. em is a relative font size, so 1.1*16px and 1.05*16px is negligible. But if your base font size is something like 100px, then it will be a 5px difference in size between 1.1em and 1.05em.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, exactly 0.05 em.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on the default character size of the browser. The default tends to be 1 em = 16px I believe, which yields 1.1 em == 1.05em == 17px in the standard setting.

If you have people which cannot see all that well, and use a large default (say 72px = 1em) then the difference would be noticable (difference = 0.05 * 72 = 3 or 4 px). Though not noticable for the person with bad sight.

Comment: @Frank True, so true. Both the answer and the funnier part :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check this out :
http://jerekdain.com/fontconversion.html

On Safari I saw a tiny difference between the 1.1em and the 1.05em but I had to use the page zoom to see it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that it depends on implementation, however do not forget, that 1em is current font size and 1.05 might get rounded anyway...